# Set different colors in a single spreadsheet cell (Excel) with Python

Tags: python, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a solution to change the color of single digits inside a cell in Excel.

An Example would be in the picture below:

[This is how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGeNd.png)

What I've tried so far is using openpyxl, xlwings and xlsxwriter and/with the help of ChatGPT.

However, none of the recommended solutions that I found worked...

Any help would be grateful! Thanks.

Edit: this is one of the solutions I tried

```
import xlwings as xw

excel_file = 'myexcel.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(excel_file)
ws = wb.sheets[0]
cell = ws.range('A1')
text = cell.value

start_position = 3
end_position = 7

# format the cell
cell.api.Font.Color = -16776961

# this line creates the error bc GetCharacters is unknown 
property, element or command
range_to_color = cell.api.GetCharacters(Start=start_position, 
Length=end_position - start_position + 1)

range_to_color.Font.Color = -65536

# save and close the worksheet
wb.save()
wb.close()
```

And one with xlsxwriter (this throws no error but it fills the background of other cells):

```
import xlsxwriter

excel_file = 'myexcel.xlsx'
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# text in cell
text = "Example"

# start and end position of the text I would like to have 
another color
start_position = 3
end_position = 7

# format the cell
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_pattern(1)  # activate background color
cell_format.set_bg_color('white')

# write text into the cell
worksheet.write('A1', text, cell_format)

# format the selected part of the text
cell_format.set_font_color('red')
worksheet.set_column(0, 0, None, cell_format, {'start_col':  start_position, 'end_col': end_position})

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Please post some/all of the solutions you have tried (regardless of if they have worked) so that we have something to start with in answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than attempting to access the relevant characters via the API endpoint (which isn't particularly clearly documented), try using something like this, which I have modified from [the docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/characters.html):

```
cell.characters[start_position:end_position].font.color = (255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: You'll need to change the comma to a colon like this: cell.characters[start_position:end_position].font.color = (255, 0, 0) - but then it works. Thanks!!